# ASP.net Identity and multi tenant multi user application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am trying to learn ASP.net MVC -

I have successfully implemented the basic authentication and authorisation.

My application is multi tenant (One DB one Schema) and multi Users.

Each user can be added to any tenant by admin.

A user will be given a list of tenants he can use upon logging in.

Then the user clicks on one tenant and enter in to the tenant's application data and can update, create etc. (invoices for example).

I am using cookie authentication, should I be adding each tenant the user is authorized to use as a claim or check on server side for authorisation when user switch between tenants.

Using cookie claim will save DB queries if I have tenant list for user as claim. But Cookie has 4k limit what if a user can access thousands of tenants such as admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can save user-tanent relation in a table , and put row id in cookie , so you can check that row when user logged in.

Comment: Would you please elaborate?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea. Cookies can be easily modified by users. A good answer will stay within the secure architecture provided by asp.net identity.